# OptaPlanner multiple entity classes with chained variables

Tags: java, optimization, optaplanner

I'm using OptaPlanner to solve a variant of a Vehicle routing problem in which the requirements of the customers to be served by vehicles vary significantly. I have a few most common customer types and want to model them using different entity classes. As it's possible for a single driver to attend different types, they should be able to form heterogeneous chains with instances of all classes on them.

I tried to do a proof of concept by modifying the VRP example. I extracted `ICustomer`, an interface for all my customers and changed the `Standstill` so that `getNextCustomer` returns an `ICustomer`. 
When I try to run it with Customer and Customer2 (a copy of the customer class), both implementing ICustomer, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entityClass 
(interface org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Standstill) has a 
InverseRelationShadowVariable annotated property (nextCustomer) with a masterClass 
(interface org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.ICustomer) which is not a 
valid planning entity.
```

In the worst case, I'll just model different customer types with enums and "ifs" in a single planning entity to get the same behaviour. Still, would be great to know if I encountered an API limitation or someone knows a better way to achieve this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

OptaPlanner fully supports polymorfism, class hierarchies, etc. We have tests for it (and have regularly found bugs for it which have been solved - as recently as for 7.3.final IIRC). See also TestDataSolution.java and the like. New reproducers are welcome as PR's of course.

The exception tells a different story. Check where you use `@InverseRelationShadowVariable`, the return type of that field/method - I suspect your refactor might not have impacted that code correctly.

Comment: You are correct about the exception from the question, it was happening because I forgot to add ICustomer as a planning entity in the solver configuration. 
After this and some other minor details, I was able to get the construction heuristic to work. It produces valid chains and the anchors (vehicles) for each customer are updated correctly.
However the inverse relation shadow getNext() is not updated neither for the vehicles nor customers.

Comment: (Further details)
I annotate the genuine PV (previousStandstill) in ICustomer interface and its both implementations Customer1 and Customer2. 
The opposite sides, @InverseRelationShadowVariable (getNext) are annotated in ICustomer and Standstill interface. I tried adding this annotation to getNext in each implementation (Customer 1 and Customer2), but it didn't help

Is it possible that having the interface with 2 implementations somehow confuses the triggering of shadow variable updaters, are my annotations wrong for this scenario? 

Any further pointers are highly appreciated!